# Count the total number of times each letter appears then calculate the probability of occurrence of each letter?

Tags: r

I'm trying to learn this in R and an exercise has a question where you're given a text document of a short story called story.txt, I imported it under the variable story. I need to do two things with it, First I need to count how much of each letter appears in the story, and the second thing is that I need the probability of occurrence of each letter, and generate a plot using the probabilities.

My idea to do this is to take the story and set everything to lower case, remove the spaces and extra characters and leave it as just letters and then count each letter, the only issue I have is that I don't know how to do that, I tried using str_count but I get an error.

Code thus far:

```
story <- readLines("story.txt")
story <- tolower(story) # i sets to lower case
story <- gsub(" ","",story) # remove all spaces
story <- gsub("\\W","",story)
storydata <- str_count(story, "a")
```

Can someone help me out? Any ideas or functions or example code? I've been stuck unable to know how to move forward.

Example of text from story:

"I tried to get you last night and the night before. The phone here's been-"

"Are you all right, Muriel?"

After running function:

[18] ""
 [19] "itriedtogetyoulastnightandthenightbeforethephoneheresbeen"
 [20] ""
 [21] "areyouallrightmuriel"

Comment: *"I tried using str_count but I get an error."* Error messages are usually very informative. What error did you get? Have you looked at `story` after making the changes with `gsub`? Does it look as you expect? If you need help debugging, you should give some sample input, say, the first 5 lines of `story.txt`.

Comment: I updated it Greg!

Comment: Still don't see your error message. My best guess is you're getting an error "str_count not found" because you haven't loaded `stringr` with `library(stringr)`. But who knows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str_split()` from stringr to split by `""`, then `table()` for counts.

```
Lorem <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet odio aliquam, viverra metus id, sodales tortor. Nulla quis pretium tellus. Aenean efficitur sodales nulla nec efficitur. Suspendisse at risus at eros pharetra tincidunt. Quisque pharetra erat non dictum tempor. Nulla feugiat, tortor a dapibus blandit, sapien est ornare felis, quis egestas tellus purus eget quam. Sed justo sapien, pulvinar quis justo vel, tristique condimentum justo. Suspendisse fermentum nibh eros, eu pretium purus molestie vel."

table(stringr::str_split(Lorem,""))
```

> table(stringr::str_split(Lorem,""))

```
    ,  .  a  A  b  c  d  D  e  f  g  h  i  j  l  L  m  n  N  o  p  q  Q  r  s  S  t  u  v 
75  9  9 29  1  3 10 14  1 51  7  4  3 39  3 21  1 16 22  2 23 15  7  1 29 40  3 40 38  5
```

to get probabilities, divide these by the total number `nchar(Lorem)`. (With R, this is vectorized, so you don't need to loop)
you can `tolower()` it first if desired.

then just wrap it in `plot()`... but probably make it look a bit better by using `sort()` first
`plot(sort(table(stringr::str_split(Lorem,""))/nchar(Lorem)))`

Comment: you may want to store the result of the first step, to subtract the occurrences of punctuation and blanks from `nchar(Lorem)`

Comment: EDIT: I figured it out, I did a data collapse and fit it all on one string! Thanks!